# (Java Minecraft 1.15) Tellraw incremental death messages

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

Recently I have been making a map, I was wondering if an incremental tell raw death message could be applied.

What I mean by this is, if you die, chat will automatically say 
"Death, 1"
Next time you die, chat will automatically change the tellraw command into
"Death, 2"
And so on.

Is this possible? Also im playing in Snapshot 19w38b

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `deathCount` scoreboard criterion.
Create a `tempDeaths` objective which will increment automatically when a player dies:

```
/scoreboard objectives add tempDeaths deathCount
```

Then create another objective called `deaths` that will be incremented manually:

```
/scoreboard objectives add deaths dummy
```

The reason for the two objectives is so that a player dying (which will increase `tempDeaths`) can be detected by testing if it is at least 1. `tempDeaths` will then be reset to 0 so that the tellraw message will not show constantly. `deaths` will also be manually incremented, which will be displayed in the message.

---

Put the following in these command blocks.

Repeating, unconditional, always active: checks each player if they have died 1 or more times and if they have, increment the `deaths` objective.

```
execute as @a[scores={tempDeaths=1..}] run scoreboard players add @s deaths 1
```

Repeating, unconditional, always active: shows "Death, #" to the player who died.

```
execute as @a[scores={tempDeaths=1..}] run tellraw @s ["Death, ",{"score":{"name":"@s","objective":"deaths"}}]
```

Chain, conditional, always active: resets `tempDeaths`. This command block needs to be placed so that one of the repeating command blocks is directly behind it (so that this command block is facing away from the repeating one and that the repeating one is facing towards this one).

```
scoreboard players set @a tempDeaths 0
```